# WebGL Fluid Simulation mouse effect implementation on website

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, webgl

Anyone has idea how to implement this: https://paveldogreat.github.io/WebGL-Fluid-Simulation/
to get mouse interaction like on this website https://advanced.team/ ?
I have been able to set up the same style through configuration, but I have now lost days on searching for how to get canvas beneath the website content like theirs or how even effect shows beneath every element...

Comment: I've acquired some information that they made their custom application based on WebGL-Fluid-Simulation idea so it not possible to get that effect by any combination of settings in code from that example just like that since it works with z-index. Which is either way true or false resulting in disabling all function in lower layer of z-index or in case Fluid Simulation z-index is in lower layer it is not visible. If anyone has other idea it would be cool to try it.